# Tuples in MDX SSAS OLAP queries (SS management studio)

Tags: tuples, mdx

I have a question about MDX tuples, I would like to gain some insight on something that seems confusing to me.

Most of the literature I have read talks about tuples being a set of co-ordinates essentially pointing to a cell which contains a measure value.  From what I understand a tuple is defined as containing only one distinct member from each dimension.  Typically when writing queries we don't specify every member for every dimension we let SSAS engine use the default members and aggregate the measure data accordingly.

Straight out of the adventure works sample OLAP database (cube) "adventure works"

A super simple query that I understand represents a tuple:

```
SELECT 
([Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].&[CY Q3],[Measures].[Sales Amount]) --Tuple                          
 ON COLUMNS                             
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

SS Management studio returns this result

[image: Result Set 1]

No problem here the tuple specified by the `&[CY Q3]` member point to the cell containing the displayed measure amount.  Clearly a tuple has been returned.

Typically though I use this sort of thing more often:

```
select 
non empty ([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter],[Measures].[Sales Amount]) --Tuple??

 ON COLUMNS                             
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Which returns all the quarter totals across all years for said measure (not a great example but it's just an example):

[image: Result set 2]

I see this result as a **set** because more than one distinct member has been returned from the same dimension (date).  In fact, by default all members are being returned if so how can it be a tuple?

So my question is this.  The parenthesis around the "tuple" in the query above, indicate to me that I'm selecting a tuple, the query engine processes and a result is returned that to me looks like a set, not because more than one cell value is returned but because more than one member from the date dimension has been used.

The query indicates that a tuple is being selected, and the query engine seems to accept it as one however the result set, includes multiple members from the same dimension and corresponding cell values indicating to me that more than one tuple will be returned --> set.

Also, The query engine throws no error when I treat it as a set and use set functions on it:

```
select 
nonempty({([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter],[Measures].[Sales Amount])}) --Set                          
 ON COLUMNS                             
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

My question is this, Assuming I am correct and that the results do in fact represent a set (a set of tuples denoted by each distinct member instance), why does the query engine allow you to specify parenthesis indicating selection of a tuple to return something that is not a tuple?

This makes more sense to me :

```
  SELECT
 nonemptycrossjoin(
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]}, --Set 1
    {[Measures].[Sales Amount]}  --Set 2
 )              
  ON COLUMNS                                
  FROM [Adventure Works]
```

At least this code reflects the result set that's returned Thoughts?
  Or is it all just Analysis Services semantics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MDX is an ambiguous language. From what I've understood, the () notation is a tuple or an operator precedence notation. And:

```
{...} , {...}
```

is actually a crossjoin:

```
{...} * {...}
```

Then when you specify a " level " where a set is expected, the level.members is defaulted. When you specify a tuple where a set is expected a singleton set is created with this only tuple. So:

```
( [level], [measures].[amount] )
```

is equivalent to:

```
crossjoin( [level].members, { [measures].[amount] } )
```

The only tuple (a member is a tuple) specified is [Measures].[Amount] which by the way does not use the () notation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you *typically* use this syntax - but I write mdx nearly every day and never use this syntax -

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY ([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter],[Measures].[Sales Amount]) ON COLUMNS                             
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I'm a little surprised it runs as it seems to be indicating to analysis services to create a tuple from a level and a measure member.

MarcP mentions that mdx is ambiguous, but I'm more in favour of saying it can be written ambiguously - it *unfortunately* fails quite graciously most of the time and you get no numbers returned or the wrong numbers - I wish it threw more errors and enforced tighter syntax rules as this might make it more understandable.

Your original script I would just use the `*` operator rather than typing out the full `crossjoin` function **when you need it** - in your script it is much more readable to move measures onto the rows and delete that tuple? Like Marc mentions SSAS's implicit use of the `MEMBERS` function - I find things more readable to include it explicitly when it is being used:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter].MEMBERS ON 0, 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 1                            
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

`[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]`

As Marc mentioned this is actually the same as `[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter].MEMBERS` in this case `MSDN` is your friend (and for mdx unlike some other ms languages I find msdn very good) - here is the definition of the `MEMBERS` function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144851.aspx

telling you the return type:

> Returns the **set** of members in a dimension, level, or hierarchy.

---

`nonemptycrossjoin`

You mentioned `nonemptycrossjoin` - this is not needed any more - just a simple crossjoin via `*` is all that is needed with the last 2 or three versions of `SSAS`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply quick question in the code snippet you have suggested in terms of the result the script gives, would you consider the result a set of 13 tuples? thanks.

Comment: @DES_3676 I'd be more inclined to consider every cell in a returned cellset to effectively be a tuple - not sure about the column headers or row headers - I'd not really class them as tuples.